# How to create radio buttons with tips with Struts2 tag <s:radio>

Tags: jsp, struts2, radio-button

I've created radio buttons with Struts2 tag  and I know the simplest usage like:

```
<s:radio id="radiobutton" name="myRadioButton" 
   list="#{'1' : 'label1', '2' : 'label2', '3' : 'label3'}"
```

but what I want is to add tips for each label which shows text when the mouse move over the radio buttons.

How can I do it with Struts2?

Comment: You need to checkout some tooltip.[cluetip](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this

```
<s:radio id="radiobutton" name="myRadioButton" title="label1" list="#{'1' : 'label1'}"/>
<s:radio id="radiobutton" name="myRadioButton" title="label2" list="#{ '2' : 'label2'}"/>
<s:radio id="radiobutton" name="myRadioButton" title="label3" list="#{ '3' : 'label3'}"/>
```

Comment: How to make this radio list as a horizontally?